# Can people on H4 EAD do private tutoring?

Tags: working, usa, h4-visa

Can people on H4 EAD do private tutoring? 

i.e. Should the private tutoring be as part of any registered company or can we do it individually and take money in cash and pay the tax appropriately for the year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an EAD you can do work in any way you want -- e.g. you can work individually, for a company, for your own self-employed company, etc. It doesn't matter.

Of course you will need to follow the appropriate tax rules for whatever form of work you do.

Comment: I was wondering can we take the amount in cash for independent tutoring? or should all these money be collected in the name of any company name to report the tax appropriately?

Comment: @barath: The method of payment, i.e. cash or check, doesn't matter. If you are working as an independent contractor, I believe they will need to give you a 1099 if their payments to you during the year exceed $600. No matter if you get a 1099 or not, you are required to report this income on your tax return (you will likely have to pay both income tax and self-employment tax).